# Excel populating row based on lookup

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel column as a dropdown list.  What i want to achieve is the following:

When the user chooses a value from the dropdown list, it should populate the row with another set of values.

e.g. Cell A1 - user chooses fruit, cell A2,A3,A4 etc should be populated based upon a lookup list, this would result in:

A1 - Fruit, A2 - Apple, A3 - Banana, A4 - Orange

Another example

A1 - Car, A2 - BMW, A3 - Honda, A4 - Suzuki, A5 - Mercedes, A6 - Audi

The number of items in each differs.

Is this possible without VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Data Validation on A1. See [Debra's site](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal01.html#Delimited)
2. Use a simple `Index` and `Match` in combo `A2:A6` to return the values allocated to A1 by referencing your data range contain your categories and values

[image]